# PHP escape unicode characters only

Tags: php, facebook, unicode, encoding

in Facebook [validation documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhooks#validate-payloads)

> Please note that we generate the signature using an escaped unicode
> version of the payload, with lowercase hex digits. If you just
> calculate against the decoded bytes, you will end up with a different
> signature. For example, the string äöå should be escaped to
> \u00e4\u00f6\u00e5.

I'm trying to make a unittest for the validation that I have, but I don't seem to be able to produce the signutre because I can't escape the payload. I've tried

```
mb_convert_encoding($payload, 'unicode')
```

But this encodes all the payload, and not just the needed string, as Facebook does.

My full code:

```
// on the unittest
$content = file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/../Responses/whatsapp_webhook.json');
        // trim whitespace at the end of the file
        $content = trim($content);

        $secret = config('externals.meta.config.app_secret');

        $signature = hash_hmac(
            'sha256',
            mb_convert_encoding($content, 'unicode'),
            $secret
        );

$response = $this->postJson(
            route('whatsapp.webhook.message'),
            json_decode($content, true),
            [
                'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'text/plain',
                'X-Hub-Signature-256' => $signature,
            ]
        );
$response->assertOk();
```

```
// on the request validation
/**
         * @var string $signature
         */
        $signature = $request->header('X-Hub-Signature-256');

        if (!$signature) {
            abort(Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
        }

        $signature = Str::after($signature, '=');
        $secret = config('externals.meta.config.app_secret');

        /**
         * @var string $content
         */
        $content = $request->getContent();

        $payloadSignature = hash_hmac(
            'sha256',
            $content,
            $secret
        );

        if ($payloadSignature !== $signature) {
            abort(Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, `mb_convert_encoding($payload, 'unicode')` converts the input to UTF-16BE, not UTF-8. You would want `mb_convert_encoding($payload, 'UTF-8')`.

For two, using `mb_convert_encoding()` without specifying the *source* encoding causes the function to *assume* that the input is using the system's default encoding, which is frequently incorrect and will cause your data to be mangled. You would want `mb_convert_encoding($payload, 'UTF-8', $source_encoding)`. [Also, you cannot reliably detect string encoding, you need to know what it is.]

For three, `mb_convert_encoding()` is entirely the wrong function to use to apply the desired escape sequences to the data. [and good lord are the google results for "php escape UTF-8" *awful*]

Unfortunately, PHP doesn't have a UTF-8 escape function that isn't baked into another function, but it's not terribly difficult to write in userland.

```php
function utf8_escape($input) {
    $output = '';
    for( $i=0,$l=mb_strlen($input); $i<$l; ++$i ) {
        $cur = mb_substr($input, $i, 1);
        if( strlen($cur) === 1 ) {
            $output .= $cur;
        } else {
            $output .= sprintf('\\u%04x', mb_ord($cur));
        }
    }
    return $output;
}

$in = "asdf äöå";

var_dump(
    utf8_escape($in),
);
```

Output:

```
string(23) "asdf \u00e4\u00f6\u00e5"
```

Comment: That worked as expected! Thank you!
Mind illustrating the if-else condition in the function?

Comment: Short version, UTF8 represents codepoints with 1-4 byte sequences. 1 byte sequences do not need to be escaped. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Examples

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to re-assemble the payload from the already decoded JSON, you should take the data directly as you received it.

Facebook sends `Content-Type: application/json`, which means PHP will not populate $_POST to begin with - but you can read the entire request body using `file_get_contents('php://input')`.

Try and calculate the signature based on *that*, that should work without having to deal with any hassles of encoding & escaping.

Comment: I am not asking about the facebook side, the signature facebook sends working as expected. I am trying to simulate the signature in sake of unit testing.

Comment: I was not talking about the Facebook side either.

Comment: oh, you mean to put the escaped value directly in `Responses/whatsapp_webhook.json`? I feel dumb as I haven't thought of that 